# mod_wsgi : Request data read error when proxying data to daemon process

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi

My wsgi application deployed on apache with mod_wsgi throws error `mod_wsgi (pid=25927): Request data read error when proxying data to daemon process: The timeout specified has expired`. My application is in production now. This error occurs four/five times a day.
My apache2 configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess my_wsgi_api processes=2 threads=15 display-name=my_wsgi_api

    WSGIScriptAlias /my_wsgi_app /opt/my_wsgi_app/start_server.wsgi
    #DocumentRoot /opt/my_wsgi_app/

    <Directory /opt/my_wsgi_app>
        allow from all
        Require all granted

        WSGIProcessGroup my_wsgi_api
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my_wsgi_api_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my_wsgi_api_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

complete log shows

```
mod_wsgi (pid=25927): Request data read error when proxying data to daemon process: The timeout specified has expired.
ERROR:root:API_ERROR : Apache/mod_wsgi request data read error: Input is already in error state.
ERROR:root:API_HANDLER_EXCEPTION : local variable 'params' referenced before assignment
mod_wsgi (pid=25923): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/my_wsgi_app/start_server.wsgi'.
```

Comment: Hi Did you solved it...? If so kindly share your solution, please

Comment: later i understood that mod_wsgi is can only handle one request per process. it is working like classic multiprocessing method. so i moved to nginx and gunicorn. it is handling request as asynchronous. also, i have no complete assumption that it happened because things i mentioned above. i presume it has something to do with content length(huge chunk of data). so, i researched some time and found out some interesting things about handling requests. Some youtuber called 'Hussein Nasser' is talked about these kinds of issues. checkout if you want.

Comment: Hey, Thanks, Can you please share how did you deploy with  Nginx and gunicorn, or if you followed any blog share it, Thanks in advance :)

Comment: i followed many bits and pieces from so many searches.1) create wsgi app in an environment. 2) install gunicorn in that environment. 3) create config file for gunicorn(you can test run your app with gunicorn alone using the config). 4) create systemd service for your gunicorn(the application is running now in gunicorn) application. 5) finally, install nginx using `apt-get install nginx`(in this you will get `etc` configuration folder structure similar to apache2 and create reverse proxy configuration in sites-available. This is the direction you should go.

Comment: I faced the same issue. It had to do with the value of Content-Length header value. I was setting it explicitly before routing each request to application server. Turns out it should be left to be done by itself.